# I am trying to render an azure map into my application but the tiles seem to be repeating. How can I limit the tile so each part's rendered only once?

Tags: azure, azure-maps

The tiles in Azure maps are repeating for me so that one location shows twice or thrice sometimes. I tried adjusting zoom but that had no effect. How can I limit this repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure I understand what you are describing, when zoomed out, you are seeing two or more "worlds" and your data repeated on them. This is known as world wrap. Like a globe you can spin it infinitely horizontally. There is an option to disable this:

```
var map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
    //Disable world wrap.
    renderWorldCopies: true,

    //Your other map options.
});
```

Here is a live demo of this: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Render%20world%20copies